# Mobile web chat, show user activity

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web

The full site chat on a desktop or on a phone in desktop mode will show user activity by fading their icon if they are in the room but not active.

The mobile web chat allows you to see who's in the room but does not fade their icon based on activity.

Can this feature be added? Since the user list isn't shown all the time, it won't be as resource heavy as the desktop version, afaik.